# Image flicker on hover - css animation

Tags: css

When the main icon is hovered the spin of the icon staggers and can not complete the rotation smoothly. Normally occurs when hover off-center on the icon. i have tried to target a different div but nothing stops it. i guess due to transparency as it spins.

Any ideas?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oxe6jg1L/26/

```css
.social-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 128px;
    position: relative;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.social-icons img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons a:hover img {
    width: 110%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -5%;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    left: 33.755%;   /*(nth-child(2).left - (50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    left: 36.25%;   /*(40% - (75% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) {
    left: 40%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    left: 48.75%; /*(60% - 3*(75% * 20%)/4*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    left: 56.25%;   /*(nth-child(4).left + (nth-child(4).width- 3*(50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) {
  top:0;

 
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s ;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s ;
   transition: transform 1s,
      opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 1s,
      opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s;

}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(3).active {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
 opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 60%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-icons">
<div class="social-icons-inner">
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="https://plus.google.com">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Linkedin Icon">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add hover to the child and make parent constant, so that when the parent is hovered, it stays hovered even if the child is rotating. Then it wont flicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you rotate the element, the `:hover` state fails because it is rotating and is out of the hover state.

Rotate the `a` element inside it, not the actual element:

```
.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) a {...}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oxe6jg1L/27/

```css
.social-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 128px;
    position: relative;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.social-icons img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons a:hover img {
    width: 110%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -5%;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    left: 33.755%;   /*(nth-child(2).left - (50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    left: 36.25%;   /*(40% - (75% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) {
    left: 40%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    left: 48.75%; /*(60% - 3*(75% * 20%)/4*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    left: 56.25%;   /*(nth-child(4).left + (nth-child(4).width- 3*(50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) a{
  top:0;

 
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s ;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s ;
   transition: transform 1s,
      opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 1s,
      opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s;

}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(3).active {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
 opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 60%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-icons">
<div class="social-icons-inner">
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="https://plus.google.com">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Linkedin Icon">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect very smooth now. Thanks for the help and description. will remember that in furture.

Comment: Glad its works. Please, read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: But we do lose the spin on mouse leaving the element, it spins when hovered, but doesnt spin back when the mouse leaves

Comment: See @PIIANTOM 's answer, that should be the right one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319477/3516008

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the element that triggers the over event has no height.
So this element is not catching event, and delegate it to inner element (the rotating one).

A height property is missing on `.social-icons-inner`

You need to add `height:100%` for this element

```css
.social-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 128px;
    position: relative;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.social-icons img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons a:hover img {
    width: 110%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -5%;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    left: 33.755%;   /*(nth-child(2).left - (50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    left: 36.25%;   /*(40% - (75% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) {
    left: 40%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    left: 48.75%; /*(60% - 3*(75% * 20%)/4*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    left: 56.25%;   /*(nth-child(4).left + (nth-child(4).width- 3*(50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}

.social-icons-inner{
    height: 100%;
}
.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) {
  top:0;

 
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s ;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s ;
   transition: transform 1s,
      opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 1s,
      opacity 1s ease-in-out,
      -webkit-transform 1s;

}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(3).active {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
 opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 60%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="social-icons">
<div class="social-icons-inner">
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="https://plus.google.com">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Linkedin Icon">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it removes the the fix below, so it open when hovering anywhere. so i add width:100px; to thatdive also, but then get the staggering loading again.